# Cakephp Uploader validation error with jQuery Form plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, cakephp, file-upload, jquery-plugins

I am using [Miles Johnson file Uploader](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader) with my CakePHP. It's working fine every time for me. But today I want to work with [jQuery Form Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) with my view but it could not catch *required* validation. Without [jQuery Form Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) its work fine. My jQuery Code as below :

```
jQuery('#ImageAddForm').ajaxForm({
    iframe:false,
    beforeSend: function() {},
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {},
    success: function() {},
    complete: function(xhr) {}
});
```

And also model validation code as below :

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
        'imagefile' => array(
            'finalPath'=>'/files/uploads/'      
        )
    ),
    'Uploader.FileValidation' => array(
        'imagefile' => array(               
            'extension' => array('pdf','zip'),
            'mimeType' => array('application/pdf','application/zip'),
            'filesize' => array(
                'value'=>104857600,
                'error'=>'Your file size is too large; maximum size 100 MB'
            ),
            'required' =>  array(
                'value' => true,
                'on' => 'create',
                'error' => 'Please choose iPad Portrait file',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Any suggestion will be grateful for me.

Comment: What actually you mean by `it could not catch required validation`?

Comment: @FazalRasel it don't show error if I not select any file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this using following code in my model :

```
function beforeValidate($options=array()) {
    $emptyfile=array('name' => '','type' => '','tmp_name' => '','error' => (int) 4,'size' => (int) 0);
    if(empty($this->data['Image']['imagefile'])){
        $this->data['Image']['imagefile']=$emptyfile;
    }   
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, then try this-

```
    'required' =>  array(
        'value' => true,
        'on' => 'create',
        'allowEmtpy' => false,
        'error' => 'Please choose iPad Portrait file',
    )
```

Comment: Already try this. But it's not working. It's display error on update case also.

Comment: And also displays error for another errors which exists. If empty file then displays file extension missing error.